# Can an instance complete its arguments later?

Tags: java, instances

I wonder if there is any way that I can declare a new instance with parameters, do not fill them, and just set them later.

Here is an example:

```
private Example example = new Example() // Need 1 parameter.

public void foo(Object arg1)
{
   example = new Example(arg1);
}
```

It is clear that this is not possible, but is there a way to do something similar to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use a parameter-less constructor, and then set the properties of the created instance later.

```
....
public Example ()
{
    this.s = null;
}

public Example (String s)
{
    this.s = s;
}
....
public void setS (String s)
{
    this.s = s;
}
....
Example ex = new Example ("something");
Example ex2 = new Example ();
ex2.setS("Something Else");
```

Comment: *You can always use a parameter-less constructor* only if such constructor is defined by you or automatically by the compiler.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Fair enough. I was assuming that class is under the control of the OP, so they can add whatever constructor they need.

Comment: Seems promising, thanks! Accepting answer in 6 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Example{
   private Object object1;
   public Example(){ 

   }

   public void setObject1(Object o){
      this.object1 = o;
   }
}
```

Now you can use this as follows:

```
Example example = new Example();
example.setObject1(someObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others and yourself already, there is no easy / official way of object construction when you can't provide the parameters needed.

You may want to look at the [Objenesis project](http://objenesis.org/). They provide clever ways of instantiation of objects in non-standard ways. To my knowledge sometimes being able to instantiate objects without providing the usually mandatory arguments declared by the constructors.